# What does the dot mean

Tags: filenames

On my reelbox (running Ubuntu) I have found a file in /etc/init that contains the following

```
# frontpanel-pre - check for frontpanel CAPs and adjust time
#

description     "check frontpanel caps"

#start on starting mountall
#start on tty-device-added DEVNAME=/dev/ttyS0

task

script
        (
        /sbin/dev_frontpanel.sh
        /sbin/reelfpctl -capability
        ) > /dev/.frontpanel.caps
        initctl emit --no-wait frontpanel-linked
end script
```

I wonder if the dot in **/dev/.frontpanel** has some special meaning in linux

I thought the output of the commands in the brackets will be written to a file called "**.frontpanel.caps**" in /dev/ but there is no such file.
In /dev/ there is a frontpanel which is a link to /dev/ttyS0

Could it be, that e.g. `echo something > /dev/.frontpanel.caps` actually sends data (something in this case) to **/dev/frontpanel** ?

What does `.caps` do then?

Comment: Isn't the `/dev/.frontpanel` a file being created by the script? So the `.` in the filename simply makes it not show in a standard `ls` command (but would in `ls -a`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filenames with a full-stop (`.`) as their first character have only one special attribute - they are "hidden" files.  Which is to say, they do not show up when using e. g. `ls` without additional parameters to explicitly request that all files, including hidden ones, be shown (e. g. `ls -a`).  This is why the CWD (`.`) and its parent (`..`) do not show up by default.

Comment: Sometimes it is just that easy. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

A file name or directory name that starts wtih a dot creates a hidden file/directory.  To see them use `ls -a` or `ls -A`  - the uppercase version doesn't display the always present `.` and `..` directories